# How to upload a file and then display its contents in Node.Js Express app?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to find an answer to this question for a long time: I need to upload a text/html file through my Node.Js express app and to save its contents into a variable for further treatment.

I can make the multipart form, of course, and post the content, but what I can access so far is only `req.files` which contains information about the file, but not the actual contents.

How do I get the actual text/html contents from the file?

I don't want to save it to my server, just pass on the content to my app and get rid of the file, so I don't want to use a module like `formidable`.

Can anyone help please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file is saved by default in a temporary folder (likely /tmp). You need to open the file, read its contents, and then delete it.

You'll want to use this API: http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

And you could do this:

```
fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile(req.files.path, function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  // data will contain your file contents
  console.log(data)

  // delete file
  fs.unlink(req.files.path, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('successfully deleted ' + req.files.path);
  });      
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've beed trying to resolve it for hours... Do you know why it actually took so long for people to respond to that question? Is it just a stupid question or did I not formulate it correctly?

Answer (score 4):

Use **multer** https://github.com/expressjs/multer with the option `inMemory: true`.

As a crude example you'll want to do something like this.

```
app.post('test', function(req, res, next) {
  var result = ''; 
  multer({
    inMemory: true,
    onFileUploadData: function(file, data) {
      result += data;
    },  
    onFileUploadComplete: function(file) {
      console.log(result); // This is what you want
    }   
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: Ok, thank you, but how do I access the contents of the file? I still see the same stuff as I saw on `req.files` without that module...

Comment: I added a crude example to help you out.

Comment: Thank you, but what if I want to call that content from another part of the application?

Comment: Use a node memory cache module or **redis**, otherwise store the file on disk temporarily.